# Force-disconnect all remote users from Applescript or shell?

Tags: terminal, applescript, remote-desktop

I have a mac that I want to automatically restart every night, but it is regularly accessed remotely from other machines in the house, and if anyone is still connected when it needs to restart it displays a prompt that it will disconnect remote users if the restart is allowed, and then just sits there waiting for a response.

Is there any way, possibly using Applescript or shell, to force a restart and automatically disconnect any remote users?

Comment: Would running `shutdown -r` from from/launchd be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so since it just abruptly kills everything running.  I'm looking for something that's clean.

Comment: That would require a script of some kind running continuously on that machine watching for it to happen and then dismissing it.  I could maybe look into it but it doesn't always happen so would require some logic etc.  I think it's a heavy-handed solution at best.

Comment: What do you mean by clean? What exactly does need to get shutdown in a way more proper than a KILL signal?

Comment: Well maybe I'm worried about nothing, but the machine is a media server so I have applications that are potentially doing things in the moment such as reading/writing to disk (Plex), backing up to Time Machine, cloud backup, etc.  I'm concerned that a simple kill could cause trouble somewhere if something is in the middle of a write operation in particular.

Comment: Yes I see how that can be, but I would still have to build in logic to detect if the dialog is there at all and react appropriately.  It just feels fragile.

Comment: Because I'm already using Applescript to execute the restart but it requires no logic.  Trouble is I can't figure out how to detect *if* a dialog is present or not.  If it was always guaranteed to be there it would be easy but since it's not... I'm working on it though.

Comment: macOS Sierra.  I am telling Finder to restart. via a simple Run AppleScript block in Automator.  If connected, users will be using standard file sharing.  This is what interrupts the restart.  I'm exploring if `shutdown -r` could be usable instead

Comment: Please make an answer instead of a comment so I can address it there instead of here.

Comment: I'm trying to `avoid extended discussions in comments.`. Also I'm experimenting with adding your code to my script, and if it works I would like to be able to mark it as best answer.

Comment: I think we're overlooking to things here - 1) why does this need to be restarted once a night and 2) *how* are the users connected?

Comment: @Allan, RE: "2) how are the users connected?" -- In one of JVC's comments  "users will be using standard file sharing", and why my answer stated **File Sharing**.

Comment: The machine in question is a media server, and I've just found that it gets unstable if not restarted regularly.  I could probably get away with less than once per day, but I just find that's the way to ensure maximum stability every day for the household.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me in **macOS Catalina** to *restart* the system and *click* the **Restart** button on the "**There is a user sharing this computer. If you restart they will be disconnected**" *dialog* that shows if Users accessing **File Sharing** on the machine are connected.

```
tell application "Finder" to restart
repeat 5 times
    try
        tell application "System Events" to click UI element "Restart" of window 1 of application process "loginwindow"
    end try
    delay 1
end repeat
```

Obviously the *number* of *loops* is arbitrary as is the *value* of the `delay` *command*. As coded it's allowing for five seconds for the dialog to appear, if it at all does.

---

[image]

Comment: I used this without the loop and although it presents an error dialog for some reason (The action Run AppleScript encountered an error), it completes the script and the machine reboots anyway.  So as far as I'm concerned, this accomplishes what I needed.  Thanks!